# Understanding op-amp circuits with extra capacitors in the feedback path

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor

When looking at circuits like this one

[image: circuit]
<sub>(source: [prohosting.com](http://dt.prohosting.com/hacks/what1.gif))</sub>

I often find (see U6-A in linked schematic) extra capacitors in the pF range slapped in parallel with the feedback resistors, although the op-amp has a buffering or gain function:

[image: schematic]

Doesn't that make it a low-pass filter instead? Is it supposed to filter out high frequencies or what other role does it play?

Comment: Reduce ringing / overshoot.

Comment: It does make it a low-pass filter, but given that it had finite bandwidth anyway, you could already say that it was a low-pass filter even without the cap.  These sort of things tend to be added to avoid amplifying signals which are *wildly* out of band - a typical example is stopping RF signals passing down audio signal paths.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody. Should I start adding those extra caps on a regular basis in my designs to filter out HF noise/signals?

Comment: It depends - I use them to reduce overall wideband noise a lot of the time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'll do the circuit analysis.

This is an inverting amplifier with a gain of
$$
|A_V| 
= \left| \frac{R_1 || -\frac{j}{\omega C_1}}{R_2}\right| 
= \left| \frac{R_1 / R_2 }{1 + j \omega R_1 C_1} \right|
= \frac{R_1 / R_2 }{\sqrt{1 + (\omega R_1 C_1)^2}}
$$
which gives you all of the information you need:

- At low frequencies (\$ \omega \approx 0\$), the gain is
  $$
  |A_V| = \frac{R_1}{R_2}  
  $$
  so the DC gain of this amplifier is the same as it was without the capacitor.
- At high frequencies, the \$1/\omega\$ term makes the gain shrink, so high frequencies noises and sharp edges are filtered out.
- The cutoff frequency of the amplifier is at
  $$
  \omega R_1 C_1 = 1 
  \implies 
  \omega = \frac{1}{R_1 C_1}
  $$
  which is fairly high, since \$C_1\$ is small.

Finally (thanks to LvW), if your circuit is ringing, this capacitor adds an extra pole in the amplifier's frequency response, which can increase the phase margin and make the circuit more stable. This is a bit more complex and depends on the properties of the op-amp, so I won't go into detail.

Comment: May I add a short correction? Ringing is not "filtered out". Such a filtering would apply to unwanted signals contained in the input signal only. Here, the feedback cap takes care that - from the beginning - ringing is inhibited or (at least) reduced. This is because this capacitor improves stability properties of the whole feedback circuit - provided the value of this cap is selected properly. It is a kind of lag compensation.

Comment: Mm, you're right - I was thinking of ordinary high-frequency filtering.

Comment: A more intuitive way to understand it is that at high frequencies the cap acts as a short, so the gain for those frequencies is reduced/cut to unity. When this is done to prevent oscillation it's sometimes called *lead compensation*; see p. 13 in http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sloa079/sloa079.pdf [ Edited by a moderator: Feb 24, 2022 That link to ti.com seems dead. A copy of the document is reported to be available [here](https://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/library/Datasheet-03/DSA0036947.pdf) ]

Comment: Isn't this circuit configuration also used as an integrator?  I'm surprised nobody's mentioned it.  (I've used it in the 'I' section of PID controllers.)

Comment: @tcrosley: The ideal integrator has no resistor in the feedback path. The resistor is added for [practical purposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Op_amp_integrator#Practical_circuit).

Comment: @RespawnedFluff The last paragraph in your linked article says "The practical integrator circuit is equivalent to an active first-order low-pass filter" which ties in with the answer above.  Nice.

Comment: Yes, that's a third way to [view it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Active_electronic_realization).

Comment: (Over the timer limit): However for actual/practical active filters second order filters are usually employed: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa049b/sloa049b.pdf

Comment: Can somebody please point me to a documentation where the complex algebra of the impedance calculation above? I'm familiar with complex numbers, but don't know the exact rules.